# Maperitive won't open on my Mac: Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: mac, maperitive

Is there anyone who can tell me what's going on here?  When I enter "mono Maperitive.exe" in the Terminal, I get this:

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/libgdiplus.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.SystemColors.get_ControlLightLight () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Deska.Theming.Theme..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/libgdiplus.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.SystemColors.get_ControlLightLight () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Deska.Theming.Theme..ctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 3):

Try these steps:

1. Install Mono Framework via Homebrew's Cask:

   `brew cask install mono-mdk`

   After this step you should have the Mono Framework accesible at
   `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework`
2. Run `mono` with a PATH to your installation:

   `env PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:$PATH mono Maperitive.exe`

*Extras:*

- If you don't have Homebrew installed, run:

  `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

  More info at [Homebrew's homepage](http://brew.sh/).
- If you don't have Cask, run:

  `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask`

  More info at [Cask's homepage](http://caskroom.io/).

By the way, consider to just run Windows XP in a virtual machine, like Virtual Box. In my personal experience it's way better.